# Android Java: Custom adapter for listview for scrolling and filtering issue

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have searched online that I need a custom adapter for my listview to solve the scrolling and filtering issue. I am using fragments since I have some tabs on my main activity.

I have tried to implement different variations of codes that I found but I could not make it work.

```java
public class Symptoms extends Fragment {
    String filename = "symptoms.txt";
    private static final String TAG = "SymptomsFragment";
    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
    String[] lines;
    ListView simpleList;
    Context context;
    private EditText filterText;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.symptoms_layout,container,false);
        simpleList = (ListView) mView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        filterText = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        try {
            lines = rf.readLines(filename, getContext());
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lines);
            simpleList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            // Print out the exception that occurred
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Unable to create "+filename+": "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
        });
        simpleList.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        simpleList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        simpleList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                String selectedSymptom = tv.getText().toString();
                if(!listItems.contains(selectedSymptom)) {
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    listItems.add(selectedSymptom);
                }else{
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    listItems.remove(selectedSymptom);
                }
                System.out.println(listItems);
            }
        });
        return mView;
    }
}
```

I am reading a text file and saving each line to an arraylist element and I am using the ArrayAdapter for my listview. I am changing the background and text color of the selected items. However when I am using the "EditText" to search on the listview or when I am scrolling the elements that were highlighted are getting shuffled (visually only). I have found many solutions online for people that were facing the same problem with their checkboxes in the listview but I was having a really hard time to implement those solutions. How should the Custom Listview adapter look like in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lines);
```

To:

```
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lines){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView tv1 = (TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                String selectedSymptom = getItem(position);
                if(listItems.contains(selectedSymptom)) {
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                }else{
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
                return tv1;
            }
        };
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error came from `lines = rf.readLines(filename, getContext());`
You can not read a file on main thread because application will be ANR

> ANR (App Not Responding) is a state in which the app is frozen and does not respond to any user gestures or draw. Unlike unresponsive gestures which are attributed to a design decision (e.g. an image that mistakenly looks like a tappable button), ANRs usually occur due to long running code that freezes the “UI thread”.

You can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) class which create a new thread in background for reading file then you can bind the result to UI.

Comment: How does this create the visually background scrolling issue of the highlighted item on the listview?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RecyclerView it would look like this:

Adapter declaration:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<IssuePOJO> myList;     // search results
    private List<IssuePOJO> myListFull; // all items

}
```

Constructor:

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> myList){
        this.context = context;
        this.myList = myList;
        myListFull = new ArrayList<>(myList); // initializing both lists with same data
    }
```

Overriding Filter:

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return listFilter;
    }

    private Filter listFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {  // checking if filter field is empty
                filteredList.addAll(myListFull);  
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim(); 
                for (String item : myListFull) {
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            myList.clear();
            myList.addAll((List) results.values); // only this list is pressented to users inside RecyclerView, myListFull 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

And inside an `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                recyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

MENU:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.damianadamski.service.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ico_search"
        android:title=""
        android:tooltipText="Search..."
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

You don't have to add `icon` but you just can customize it to fit into your application.

Comment: Yeah but I do not have a menu

Comment: You dont need to create whole menu for this, it will be just a search icon, insead of menu and when you click it it will show you field, where you can type your search text. Check my answer for `menu` `XML`

Comment: But this not the problem, as you can read I have everything set up both the search field and the elements of the listview, the problem is that when I am selecting an items and I am scrolling or searching the selection is getting suffled

Comment: In the question I never asked for a menu, I am asking how to solve the shuffling issue when I am scrolling or searching in the listview